# My code won't select a new random number

Tags: python

I'm creating a mini project where a user has to guess the randomly selected number between 1 and 10.

My code works up to the point where the user guesses the correct number. It'll loop back up to "restart = 1" but won't generate a new number?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean - https://gyazo.com/1b6c9afc17997e7a0ee059a8b0eeb89e
As you see in that circumstance, the number wouldn't change from 6?

It'd be awesome to have any help possible!

```
# Useful module for selecting random numbers
import random

# Return to this point when user guesses the correct number
restart = 1

while (restart < 10):
    # Variable that chooses a random number
    Random_Number = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))

    # Loop back to this point
    loop = 1

    # Checks if users number is correct or not
    while (loop < 10):

        personStr = input("Guess the random number from 1 - 10?: ")
        person = int(personStr)

        if person == Random_Number:
            print ("You are correct!, the number is", Random_Number)
            print ("Try to guess the new number!")
            restart = restart + 1

        elif Random_Number < person:
            print ("Your number is smaller than your selected number, try again!")
            loop = loop + 1

        else:
            print ("Your number is larger than your selected number, try again!")
            loop = loop + 1
```

Comment: You aren't exiting the inner loop after the player guesses the number.  Just add a break after incrementing restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a break to exit the loop.

```
# Useful module for selecting random numbers
import random

# Return to this point when user guesses the correct number
restart = 1

while (restart < 10):
    # Variable that chooses a random number
    Random_Number = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))

    # Loop back to this point
    loop = 1

    # Checks if users number is correct or not
    while (loop < 10):

        personStr = input("Guess the random number from 1 - 10?: ")
        person = int(personStr)

        if person == Random_Number:
            print ("You are correct!, the number is", Random_Number)
            print ("Try to guess the new number!")
            restart = restart + 1
            break # add a break here

        elif Random_Number < person:
            print ("Your number is smaller than your selected number, try again!")
            loop = loop + 1

        else:
            print ("Your number is larger than your selected number, try again!")
            loop = loop + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `break` for second loop:

```
if person == Random_Number:
    print ("You are correct!, the number is", Random_Number)
    print ("Try to guess the new number!")
    restart = restart + 1
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Random_Number = random.randint(1, 10)` for generating random integers from 1 to 10 and use `break;` after your conditional statements.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are seeking [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) then use loop as your index, like so:

```
# Useful module for selecting random numbers
import random

# Return to this point when user guesses the correct number
restart = 0

rand_nums = random.shuffle(range(1, 11)).
# ^Assuming you only want one of each in range (1,11)

while restart < 10:
    restart += 1   
    # Loop back to this point
    loop = 1

    # Checks if users number is correct or not
    while loop < 10:
        loop += 1

        personStr = input("Guess the random number from 1 - 10?: ")
        person = int(personStr)

        if person == rand_nums[restart]:
            print ("You are correct!, the number is", rand_nums[restart])
            print ("Try to guess the new number!")
            break
        elif rand_nums[restart] < person:
            print ("Your number is smaller than your selected number, try again!")
        else:
            print ("Your number is larger than your selected number, try again!")
```

EDIT: And as others have said, you may be wanting to [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=break#grammar-token-break_stmt) out of your conditionals. The code above now includes that also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But now the code is breaking? This is the error I get now? - https://gyazo.com/16294bbbcb6c20d8f4643bf77cb6076e and this is what I changed - https://gyazo.com/8e9df64152e0692605e7f83df93217e2